# SqlException: Invalid object name 'Products'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a database-first approach ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web
app.

I decided to use Microsoft's `AdventureWorks` sample database for this.

In short, I am trying to get some information from a table called `Production.Product`.

Here is the code:

`Product` Class:

```
 public class Product
 {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
    // More properties.
 }
```

Context:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I add the `AppDbContext` in the `Program` class as every developer would, nothing special.

For testing purposes I use the `HomeController` to get the data.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // I have the view created.
    public IActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        var model = _context.Products.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And when I go to the `GetProducts` view, I am greeted with this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SqlException: Invalid object name 'Products'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)

I doubled check the connection string. Tried renaming the `Product` class to `Production_Product`.

Comment: How have you defined the EF configuration for your model classes? Since the `Product` table is in the `Production` schema, you need to explicitly define it that way. Either by using a data annotation `[Table("Product", "Production")]` or by using the Fluent API `entity.ToTable("Product", "Production");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In short, I am trying to get some information from a table called
> Production.Product.And when I go to the GetProducts view, I am greeted
> with this error:"SqlException: Invalid object name 'Products'". I
> doubled check the connection string. Tried renaming the Product class
> to Production_Product.

Well, based on your description, I have successfully reproduce your issue. As you can see below:

[image]

**Why the error for:**

Generally the exception telling us, `AppDbContext` property  `Products` doesn't matched with the `AdventureWorks` database schema or table name. Let have a look on the blow screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the database schema table name consturction followed format `Production.Product`. Thus, while your entity executing query its searching by `DbSet<Product> Products` but `Product` obviously doesn't exists or matched as a result we ended with with the error.

**How to resolve:**

We can solve the error following couple of ways. Here I am completely agreed with [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s). Therefore, I am adding, complete implementations.

Way: 1 Using Entity framework Data Annotation:

If you prefer using data annotations of entity framework so you have to modify your `Product` class as following:

```
    [Table("Production.Product")]
    public class Product
    {
       
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** Main point is that, database schema name should be same as your model or class. You can get more details in [official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#table-and-column)

Way: 2 Using Fluent API Validation:

In this scenario you should modify your code same as blow:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Production.Product");
           

        }
```

Full DbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
       
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
     

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Production.Product");
           

        }
    }
```

**Note:** As said earlier, database table name must be same with the `AppDbContext` entity name. You can get [more details here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties)

Way: 3 Rename database schema table name:

We even can rename our database table name from `Production.Product` to `Product` or we can create new table with name `Product`. Either way would resolve the issue. Have a look below:

[image]

This would also resolve your issue accordingly.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** The takeaways are, your database table name should be matched with your entity model which defined in `AppDbContext`. On top of that, you could resolve the issue following either way has been described above.

Answer (score 0):

In function

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Production.Product");          
    }
```

Just change its content to be

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product", "Production");
```

You hav to specify the schema as separate parameter, not within table name.